# Fortran ftell returning to wrong position

Tags: fortran

Here is a snippet of simple code that reads line from file, then returns to previous position and re-reads same line:

```
program main
  implicit none
  integer         :: unit, pos, stat
  character(128)  :: buffer

  ! Open file as formatted stream
  open( NEWUNIT=unit, FILE="data.txt", ACCESS="stream", FORM="formatted", STATUS="old", ACTION="read", IOSTAT=stat )
  if ( stat /= 0 ) error stop

  ! Skip 2 lines
  read (unit,*) buffer
  read (unit,*) buffer

  ! Store position
  pos = ftell(unit)

  ! Read & write next line
  read (unit,*) buffer
  write (*,*) "buffer=", trim(buffer)

  ! Return to previous position
  call fseek(unit,pos,0)
  ! pos = ftell(unit)   ! <-- ?!

  ! Read & write next line (should be same output)
  read (unit,*) buffer
  write (*,*) "buffer=", trim(buffer)

  ! Close file stream
  close (UNIT=unit)

end program main
```

The "data.txt" is just a dummy file with 4 lines:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Now when I compile the snippet (gfortran 9.3.0) and run it, I get an answer:

```
 buffer=3
 buffer=4
```

which is wrong, as they should be same. More interestingly when I add an additional `ftell` (commented line in the snippet) after 'fseek' I get correct answer:

```
 buffer=3
 buffer=3
```

Any idea why it does that? or am I using `ftell` and `fseek` incorrectly?

Comment: Note that ftell and fseek are obsolete non-standard compiler extensions that won't work in all compilers and should not be used in new code. If you are using `access="stream"` you should be using `inquire` and `read(unit,pos=)`.

Comment: Second @VladimirF, who beat me to it by a second - look at Inquire( .... pos = ... ) and Write(  ... pos = ... ) for the standard way to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gfortran's documentation for `FTELL` and `FSEEK` clearly states that these routines are provided for backwards compatibility with g77.  As your code is using `NEWUNIT`, `ERROR STOP`, and `STREAM` access, you are not compiling old moldy code.  You ought to use standard conforming methods as pointed out by @Vladimir.

A quick debugging session shows that `FTELL` and `FSEEK` are using a 0-based reference for the file position while the `inquire` method of modern Fortran is 1 based.  There could be an off-by-one type bug in gfortran, but as `FTELL` and `FSEEK` are for backwards  compatibility with g77 (an unmaintained 15+ year old compiler), someone would need to do some code spelunking to determine the intended behavior.  I suspect none of the current, active, gfortran developers care enough to explore the problem.  So, to fix your problem

```
program main

  implicit none

  integer pos, stat, unit
  character(128) buffer

  ! Open file as formatted stream
  open(NEWUNIT=unit, FILE="data.txt", ACCESS="stream", FORM="formatted", &
  &  STATUS="old", ACTION="read", IOSTAT=stat)

  if (stat /= 0) stop

  ! Skip 2 lines
  read (unit,*) buffer
  read (unit,*) buffer

  ! Store position
  inquire(unit, pos=pos)

  ! Read & write next line
  read (unit,*) buffer
  write (*,*) "buffer=", trim(buffer)

  ! Reread & write line (should be same output)
  read (unit,*,pos=pos) buffer
  write (*,*) "buffer=", trim(buffer)

  ! Close file stream
  close (UNIT=unit)

end program main
```